# How to add a conditional input to this cGAN code that already has a conditional input?

Tags: python, input, conditional-statements, generative-adversarial-network

```
def train(self, epochs, batch_size=128, save_interval=50):

    # Load the dataset
#   pdb.set_trace()
    X_train = np.load('areadata_cGANvf.npy')
    numpts = X_train.shape[0]
    vol_frac = np.load('vfdata_cGANvf.npy')
    vol_frac = np.expand_dims(vol_frac,axis=1)
#   pdb.set_trace()
```

^ this is a part of the code. the vol_frac variable is a conditional input (the file it loads is an array of a bunch of scalars like "5" and "4"). I want to add another conditional input to this code (also an array of scalars). Can I do this?

[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z6Oi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You add as many conditional inputs as you want. How you decide to combine them with the original input is up to you but typically, they are passed through an embedding layer and upscaled so that you can stack them to the original input as additional channels.  One channel can be for one conditional variable and one for another

Comment: Hi! Thanks. Clarifying question.  Let's say I wanted to add this conditional input:  SecondInput= np.load('Second_cGANvf.npy'). Then...would I add it into the rest of my code like this:

Comment: # ---------------------
            #  Train Discriminator
            # ---------------------

            # Select a random half of images
            idx = np.random.randint(0, 6400, batch_size)
            imgs = X_train[idx]
            vfs = vol_frac[idx]
            vfs = np.repeat(vfs,self.latent_dim,axis=1)  snd=SecondInput[idx] snd=np.repeat(snd,self.latent_dim,axis=1)

Comment: I can't read your code from the comment because it is not clear. But what I meant in my answer is that you can add it as you did the first conditional input(which you already did from the title of your question)

Comment: Hi! I just added a pic (click 'see picture'). So, do you see how in the code below it says "vfs = vol_frac[idx]" and then "vfs = np.repeat(vfs,self.latent_dim,axis=1)" . Would I just repeat these exact two lines for my second conditional input?

Comment: Just commenting again in case you didn't get notified from my other comment. Thanks btw :) @Ken4scholars